# randomwalk.sty missing after download

Tags: miktex2.9, randomwalk

Downloaded `randomwalk`, several repeats. `\usepackage{randomwalk}` results in ERROR: `randomwalk.sty` missing. I would download `randomwalk.sty` if only I knew which MikTex2.9 folder to put it into.

Comment: I believe that, with MikTeX, you should use its download manager (if that's the right word), not do it manually.  But if all else fails, perhaps you can put it in the same folder as the `.tex` file as a temporary workaround until someone explains how MikTeX works.

Comment: @jon I had used both the Admin and the User Package Managers `MikTex` offers, in both cases the download seemed to go as it should, and the list shows randomwalk to have been installed. I did manually put a `randomwalk.sty` into the same folder as my `.tex` file, unfortunately the compilation bombs out. Checked the `.sty` line for line and compared it with the published .pdf documentation, all seems OK. I may have to leave this for a rainy day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MiKTeX package is faulty. You can see this if you check the file list in the properties context menu of the package:

[image]

Such packaging error happens. When you see them: Make a bug report at the MiKTeX bug tracker https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/?source=navbar and as a workaround until it has been resolved put the sty in your current document folder.

Answer (score 1):

MikTeX has a built-in package manager you should use to install packages. Just open "MikTeX Package Manager (Admin)", search for "random" and install `randomwalk` (using the install command from the menu).

[image: randomwalk]

If you really have to do it manually, please read the manuals on MikTeXs functionality of multiple roots (in a nutshell: just extract it anywhere, go to the MikTeX settings and tell MikTeX that this is an alternative TeX tree).

Comment: I had done as you suggested. By the way, what is the difference between the two: `Package Manager` and `Package Manager (Admin)`? I usually use both, just in case.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth The difference is simply that the admin version installs it in a system-wide tree whereas the other one just for your user.